# loop into js object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

i have this js object:

```
var tags = [{ 'x' : '42','y' : '25','id' : '1', 'linea' : '1'},{ 'x' : '378','y' : '24','id' : '2', 'linea' : '1'}];
```

i try to loop in this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){

            var x = tags[i].x -10;
            var y = tags[i].y -10;


            var offsetX = x + 20;
            var offsetY = y + 20;


            if( left >= x && left <= offsetX ){ 

                $(myDiv).bind('click',function(){
                    document.location.href = 'x.php?a='+ tags[i].linea +'&b=' + tags[i].id;
                }).css('cursor','pointer');

            }else{
                $(myDiv).unbind('click').css('cursor','none');
            }
        }
```

But i loose the first! 
Is this the correcy way??
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Variable scope.. change to this and it should work fine:

```
var lineA = tags[i].linea;
var id = tags[i].id;
$(myDiv).bind('click',function(){
    document.location.href = 'x.php?a='+ lineA  +'&b=' + id;
}).css('cursor','pointer');
```

The problem is with `i` being the loop iterator, so when you click `myDiv` it will have the last value always.

**Edit**: after looking into it, I could see you are taking the wrong approach. What you are after is identifying where the user clicked inside the `<div>` and redirect to different location according to your array. For this, such code should work:

```
var tags = [{ 'x' : '42','y' : '25','id' : '1', 'linea' : '1'},{ 'x' : '378','y' : '24','id' : '2', 'linea' : '1'}];

$("#myDiv").bind('click',function(event) {
    var left = event.pageX - $(this).position().left;
    for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){    
        var x = tags[i].x -10;
        var y = tags[i].y -10;
        var offsetX = x + 20;
        var offsetY = y + 20;
        if( left >= x && left <= offsetX ){ 
            var lineA = tags[i].linea;
            var id = tags[i].id;
            document.location.href = 'x.php?a='+ lineA  +'&b=' + id;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

The code should be pretty clear, anyway <strike>it's not possible to have only parts of the element with hand cursor - I advise you not to mess too much as it will be really complicated</strike>.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yEFXP/).

**Edit 2**: Having the "clickable" parts of the element with different cursor is easier than I initially thought, you just have to handle the `onmousemove` event as well  and in there set the cursor:

```
var posLeft = $("#myDiv").position().left;

$("#myDiv").bind('click',function(event) {
    var tag = GetHoveredTag(event);
    if (tag) {
        var lineA = tag.linea;
        var id = tag.id;
        document.location.href = 'x.php?a='+ lineA  +'&b=' + id;
    }
}).bind("mousemove", function(event) {
    var tag = GetHoveredTag(event);
    var cursor = (tag) ? "pointer" : "";
    $(this).css("cursor", cursor);
});

function GetHoveredTag(event) {
    var left = event.pageX - posLeft;
    for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){    
        var x = tags[i].x -10;
        var y = tags[i].y -10;
        var offsetX = x + 20;
        var offsetY = y + 20;
        if( left >= x && left <= offsetX )
            return tags[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEFXP/1/).

Comment: You can also add .bind(tags[i]) after the function declaration to make the 'this' vartiable scope to the current tag. This will prevent you from introducing a kinds of helper variables.

Comment: Ok, but why in this coordinates  'x' : '42','y' : '25' ( the first one ) i CAN'T see the curson pointer?? Only in the second one..

Comment: That won't help.... `lineA` and `id` will refer to the values of the last iteration of the loop. You did not introduce a new scope, so the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

You don't loose the first (sounds like it was a car key). You problem is your anonymous function, that closes over its parent scope when executed( for your `.bind()` method). It creates, what we call, a *Closure*.

Its a very common mistake in ECMAscript there. You need to invoke an additional context to avoid this issue.

```
$(myDiv).bind('click',(function( index ){
    return function() {
        document.location.href = 'x.php?a='+ tags[index].linea +'&b=' + tags[index].id;
    };
}( i ))).css('cursor','pointer');
```

If you don't do that, all of those anonymous function context will share the same parent context in their scope-chain. Without describing that too much in detail now, it'll end up that all event handlers would reference the same variable `i`.

Beside that, it looks like you're binding multiple click event handlers to the same element `myDIV`. Each handler would cause the browser to redirect to another url, so, this will bring trouble. I can't even tell if the first or the last handler will win this race.